# В чем разница между == и ===?

Tags: javascript, javascript-faq

Мне кажется, что операторы `==` и `===` работают одинаково. Например:

```
1 == 1   // true
1 === 1  // true
1 == 2   // false
1 === 2  // false
```

Оператор `==` короче и часто встречается в других языках программирования. Так зачем `===` вообще?

Comment: После прочтения ответа возникает закономерный вопрос: а зачем `==` вообще?

Comment: @VladD Да, мне тоже любопытно. Много специалистов JavaScript, например Douglas Crockford, считают, что это было ошибка. Кажется, что дизайнер JavaScript, как и дизайнеры PHP, думал что будет легче для программистов если язык преобразывает типы автоматическим образом. А мне кажется наоборот, что надо про типы думать больше, когда неожиданно преобразываются.

Comment: А сие точно не дубль?

Comment: @nick_n_a, это скорее оригинал :-)

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/14227417

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Операторы `===` и `!==` являются операторами *строгого* сравнения. Значит, если операнды имеют разные типы, то не являются равными. Например:

```
1 === "1" // возвращает false
1 !== "1"  // возвращает true
null === undefined // возвращает false
```

Операторы `==` и `!=` являются операторами, скажем, *грубого* сравнения. То есть, если операнды имеют разные типы, JavaScript пытается как-то преобразовать их, чтобы стали сравнимыми. Например:

```
1 == "1" // возвращает true
1 != "1" // возвращает false
null == undefined // возвращает true
```

Интересно заметить, что в отличие от `===`, оператор `==` не является [транзитивным](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C):

```
"0" == 0 // true
0 == ""  // true
"0" == ""// false
```

Не очень легко помнить правила этого грубого сравнения, и иногда бывает, что оно работает неожиданным образом. Поэтому, я рекомендую использовать `===` вместо `==`.

Даже я не помню мелкие детали оператора `==`, так что посмотрим в [спецификации, пункт 11.9.3](http://es5.javascript.ru/x11.html#x11.9.3):

> ## Алгоритм сравнения абстрактного равенства
>
> Сравнение x == y, где x и y являются значениями, возвращает true или false. Это сравнение производится следующим образом:
>
> 1. Если Type(x) такой же, что и Type(y), то
>
>    1. Если Type(x) – Undefined, вернуть true.
>
>       Если Type(x) – Null, вернуть true.
>
>       Если Type(x) – Number, то
>
>       1. Если x – NaN, вернуть false.
>
>          Если y – NaN, вернуть false.
>
>          Если x имеет такое же числовое значение, что и y, вернуть true.
>
>          Если x равно +0 и y равно −0, вернуть true.
>
>          Если x равно −0 и y равно +0, вернуть true.
>
>          Вернуть false.
>
>       Если Type(x) – String, то вернуть true, если x и y имеют абсолютно одинаковую последовательность символов (одинаковой длины и с одинаковыми символами в соответствующих позициях). В противном случае вернуть false.
>
>       Если Type(x) – Boolean, вернуть true, если x и y оба являются или true, или false. В противном случае вернуть false.
>
>       Вернуть true, если x и y относятся к одному и тому же объекту. В противном случае вернуть false.
>
>    Если x равно null и y – undefined, вернуть true.
>
>    Если x – undefined и y – null, вернуть true.
>
>    Если Type(x) – Number и Type(y) – String,
>      вернуть результат сравнения x == ToNumber(y).
>
>    Если Type(x) – String и Type(y) – Number,
>      вернуть результат сравнения ToNumber(x) == y.
>
>    Если Type(x) – Boolean, вернуть результат сравнения ToNumber(x) == y.
>
>    Если Type(y) – Boolean, вернуть результат сравнения x == ToNumber(y).
>
>    Если Type(x) – либо String, либо Number, и Type(y) – Object,
>      вернуть результат сравнения x == ToPrimitive(y).
>
>    Если Type(x) – Object и Type(y) –либо String, либо Number,
>      вернуть результат сравнения ToPrimitive(x) == y.
>
>    Вернуть false.

Comment: Но и с фанатизмом подходить к `===` не нужно: например, в выражении `typeof a === typeof b` вполне достаточно `==`. Да и ситуации, в которых есть уверенность в типе операндов, не так уж и редки.

Comment: @Regent В принципе я согласен, я против фанатизма, хотя для меня легче просто везде использовать `===`, чем каждый раз думать, "достаточно ли `==`?"

Comment: Что-то в алгоритме сравнения ветвь для двух object'ов потерялась.

Comment: А нет, нашёл. Пункт 1.6.

Comment: у вас ошибка во втором примере (грубое сравнение) null === undefined // возвращает true, лишнее равно стоит