# Как создать файл .gitignore в Windows?

Tags: windows, git, файлы, gitignore

Когда пытаюсь создать файл `.gitignore` в Windows, приводит к ошибке:

[image: You must type a file name]

Как можно создать файл `.gitignore`?

Comment: Связанный вопрос:  http://superuser.com/q/64471

Comment: легко создается в Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- Можно создать файл `.gitignore.`, с точкой в конце. Точка в конце исчезает автоматическим образом.
- Тоже возможно создать файл используя `cmd.exe`:

  ```
  type nul > .gitignore
  ```

Comment: Ты на свой вопрос отвечаешь? :)

Comment: @SergeySnegirev Да, я [часто](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435546/176684) [так](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431662/176684) [делаю.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/434114/176684)

Comment: опа, нативный эквивалент touch, о котором я не сумел подумать! Круто!

Comment: @PeterOlson Ещё можно сразу же ответчать на вопрос, ещё до того, как его опубликуешь - есть в форме галка "Ответить на собственный вопрос"

Comment: Хмм, не совсем эквивалент touch, поскольку touch ещё и дату-время модификации исправляет, а `type nul >>файл` создает файл, но не меняет его время, если он уже был. Но для цели "создать файл нулевой длины" решение замечательное.

Comment: @Vesper, а ещё если слезть с XP, да таки перейти на более свежие версии Windows, то окажется, что можно просто открыть любой текстовый редактор(хоть даже "блокнот"), набить содержимое и просто сохранить как файл с именем `.gtignore`. А по поводу `touch` - в PowerShell есть `New-Item` как его многофункциональный аналог, ещё с первых версий - если прям "ломает ностальгия", то можно ему алиас `touch` и назначить(ну плюс с Set-Time-ом, что бы прям совсем аналогично работало).

Comment: Интересно, а что мешало в XP создать файл из блокнота? Насколько я помню свой опыт с win98 - достаточно было изменить маску фильтра файлов `*.txt (Текстовый документ)` на `*.* (Все файлы)`.

Answer (score 10):

1. Создай файл gitignore.txt
2. Отредактируй в текстовом редакторе по вкусу
3. Далее шифт + правый клик мышкой внутри папки, где лежит файл
4. Выбираешь "Open command window here" или как это там по-русски
5. Запустится cmd.exe уже в этой папке. Пишешь `ren gitignore.txt .gitignore`, файл переименовывается.

Comment: +1 Это тоже вполне допустимый ответ, и вы сумели отвечать чуть до меня.

Comment: [похожий ответ от @ajcw на en.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12298593/4279). Если вы его использовали, то укажите ссылку на ответ и имя автора в вашем ответе.

Answer (score 9):

Можно скачать готовый `.gitignore` с GitHub. Там есть специальный репозиторий, в котором сохраняются шаблоны `.gitignore` для разных языков и фреймворков.

https://github.com/github/gitignore

Разумеется, потом его можно отредактировать, хоть вовсе оставить пустым.

<sub>Сам GitHub использует этот репозиторий, когда предлагает добавить .gitignore во вновь создаваемый репозиторий. Поэтому ссылка почти наверняка не сломается.</sub>

---

Из git bash или cygwin работают следующие способы:

```
touch .gitignore
echo '' > .gitignore
```

Comment: Хм. Обычно "скачать" сильно не равно "создать", хотя конечный результат будет одинаковым.

Comment: @Vesper: зато сразу готовый результат, избавляющий от вопросов "что положить в .gitignore для фреймворка XYZ"

Comment: Спасибио, полезная вещь. Не знаю как тогда в 2015-м, но сейчас при создании репозитория можно сразу подключить гит игнор из данного списка.

Comment: @l2banners если на гитхабе создаёте, то да, можно. Кажется, для этого и был сделан репозиторий с шаблонами.

Answer (score 2):

Ну раз Total Commander, то так:

- заходим в нужную папку
- жмем Shift-F4, вписываем имя файла как есть `.gitignore`, жмем Enter
- открывается редактор, указанный в настройках Total Commander (какой-нибудь легковесный редактор с подсветкой синтаксиса, например)
- прописываем содержимое, жмем сохранить

Собственно, все. Никаких манипуляций с именем файла не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

## Total Commander и все операции с папками и файлами

Всякие разные операции с файлами классно проделываю в Windows 98 - Windows 10 в любимом редакторе: **Total Commander**

- [x] Создать .gitignore.txt
- [x] Двойной клик по имени файла
- [x] Удалить выделенное .txt
- [x] Подтверждаю нажатием

#### P.s. - Всегда проверяем кодировку файла: UTF-8

Comment: Total Commander это разве не для старперов со слабыми компьютерами?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian а что нынче у хипстеров в моде?

Comment: @insolor без понятия, но чем стандартный explorer не угодил?

Comment: В Total Commander все делается намного проще: Shift-F4 - вводим имя файла `.gitignore`, открывается редактор.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, тем что он "однопанельный", тем что у него нет мега удобной настраиваемой панели инструментов, отсутствием встроенной командной строки, не запоминает состояние между сессиями, ну и куча других "отсутствий".

Comment: @insolor больше похоже на привычку, т.к. все перечисленное есть и без коммандера.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54009/discussion-between-insolor-and-vladimir-gamalian).

Answer (score 0):

Есть простой вариант, создайте обычный текстовый фаил .txt, не важно как будет называться, затем откройте его, перейдите в раздел сохранить как, далее впишите имя фаила .gitignore, далее, ниже в разделе "тип фаила" выбирите все фаилы *.* и все, переименуется