# Как добавить игнор лишних файлов в репозиторий github?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

Я создал репозиторий под проект на Java, но не выбрал настройку файла gitignore под Java-проект.
Как добавить игнор лишних файлов под проект Java в репозиторий github?

Comment: Синтаксис `.gitignore` допольно прост, так что думаю несложно будет его вам создать и вручную. Но ответить на вопрос в текущем виде невозможно т.е. "проект" он бывает совершенно разный в зависимости от типа и используемой среды.

Comment: Если вы на Windows, вам понадобится этот вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/438367/181472

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Создайте в корне файл `.gitignore`:

```
*.class

# Mobile Tools for Java (J2ME)
.mtj.tmp/

# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.ear

# virtual machine crash logs, see http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_hotspot.xml
hs_err_pid*
```

[Java.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Java.gitignore)

[.gitignore для остальных языков и фреймворков](https://github.com/github/gitignore)