# Как клонировать проект из конкретной ветки GIT?

Tags: git, git-clone

Есть репозиторий на гитлабе. В репе 2 ветки.

В одной весь сайт (master), вместе с папкой uploads, logs и прочим шлаком, который мне локально никуда вообще не уперся. 
Во второй ветке только то, что нужно для разработки.

Создаю проект в PhpStorm из отсутствующих файлов, указываю репозиторий, но шторм же тянет мастер,а мастер почти 7 гигабайт. Можно как-то заставить шторм клонировать из конкретной ветки при создании проекта?

Answer (score 4):

Можно сделать репозиторий по нужной удаленной ветке, а потом по ней создать проект в PHPStorm:

```
git clone git://repository/project.git -b remote_branch
```

Но вообще у вас не должны быть upload, logs и прочих данных в ветке master, да и вообще под git'ом.

Answer (score 3):

> но шторм же тянет мастер, а мастер почти 7 гигабайт

Вы не слишком сэкономите место таким образом и вот почему. Команда `git clone` выполняется в два этапа:

1. Копирование хранилища из удалённого репозитория целиком. Данные выкачиваются упакованными в блобы (Binary Large OBject), к ним в комплекте идут данные о структуре коммитов и их взаимосвязи. Выкачиваются все коммиты во всех ветках, в том числе в той, которая занимает 7 Gb.
2. Checkout конкретного коммита. По умолчанию - того, куда смотрит HEAD на удалённом репозитории. Как подсказывает Daniel-664, с помощью параметра `-b remote_branch` можно поменять умолчание и сразу получить нужную ветку.

Проблема в том, что пока есть хоть один коммит, в котором лежит огромный файл с логами или другими файлами, эти данные хранятся в репозитории. Если лог менялся и коммитился несколько раз, то там хранится каждая версия.  Поэтому блобы от этой ветки могут занимать даже больше места, чем файлы из конкретного коммита.

Чтобы вечно не хранить эти ненужные файлы, можно удалить из репозитория соответствующие им коммиты и бинарные файлы. Есть существенное ограничение: это перепишет историю репозитория. Если есть другие разработчики, им потребуется клонировать репозиторий заново.

Есть несколько способов очистить репозиторий:

1. Просто удалить ветку, в которой закоммичены логи, а потом почистить сборщиком мусора. Не подходит, если в коммитах ветки есть другие ценные изменения.
2. С помощью команды `filter-branch --tree-filter` или `filter-branch --index-filter`. Она редактирует каждый коммит в истории и "пересохраняет" его (на самом деле создает новую цепочку коммитов, но их атрибуты останутся прежними и ветка будет смотреть на новый последний коммит.
3. Воспользоваться утилитой [bfg-repo-cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), которая делает то же, что и filter-branch, но быстрее и удобнее:

   ```
   # клонируем наш репозиторий
   git clone --mirror git://example.com/my-repo.git

   # самое время сделать бэкап
   cp my-repo.git my-repo.git.backup

   # удаляем ненужную папку c помощью BFG
   java -jar bfg.jar --delete-folders logs  my-repo.git

   # Заходим, сбрасываем reflog и запускаем сборщик мусора
   cd my-repo.git
   git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive

   # заливаем обратно в гитлаб
   git push -f
   ```

В будущем, чтобы логи, базы данных и тому подобное не попадало в репозиторий, используйте `.gitignore`:

- [Как добавить игнор лишних файлов в репозиторий github?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/442235/181472)
- [Что должно и не должно быть в .gitignore для любого языка и IDE?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474556/181472)