# Как правильно добавить файл gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

Если я правильно понял, то файл `gitignore` создается как обычный файл и в который нужно записать, что нужно игнориоровать

И вот тут хочу уточнить

- Добавляю я этот файл вот так? `echo "# project_name" » gitignore` ? Но какое расширение имеет этот файл?
- Положить его нужно если я правильно понял в корень проекта, если мне нужно сделать игнор для всего проекта
- И последнее, посоветуйте что должно быть внутри файла? Я вот, что собрал

  > '#' Lines starting with '#' are considered comments.
  >
  > '#' Ignore any file named foo.txt.
  >
  > foo.txt
  >
  > '#' Ignore (generated) html files,
  >
  > *.html
  >
  > '#' except foo.html which is maintained by hand.
  >
  > !foo.html
  >
  > '#' Ignore objects and archives.
  >
  > *.[oa]
  >
  > .idea/
  >
  > .target/
  >
  > .out/

Comment: Файл должен называться `.gitignore`

Comment: https://github.com/github/gitignore

Comment: @nzeemin следуя примеру github.com/github/gitignore  не файл должен называться `.gitignore` , а его расширение... Верно?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko в мире unix всё, что начинается с точки - скрытый файл, не более

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что должно и не должно быть в .gitignore для любого языка и IDE?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474556/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-gitignore-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8-ide)

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, "*следуя примеру*" - это значит, что если нужен файл для языка C++, то нужно взять файл `C++.gitignore` и переименовать его в `.gitignore`.

Comment: расширение - это не более чем абстракция, которая принята как часть общей конвенции. Файл не обязан иметь его или часть до него.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Файл должен быть обычным **текстовым** файлом, без расширения.

Называться он должен `.gitignore` (с точкой в начале).

Если у вас linux (или unix-like), то да, можно создать его через команду `echo '' > .gitignore` или `touch .gitignore`. Но если вы не понимаете зачем это, то можете создать его в вашем любимом текстовом редакторе (только расширение убрать не забудьте).

Если у вас windows: [как создать файл .gitignore в Windows?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/438367/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-gitignore-%d0%b2-windows)

У github есть отличный [сборник файлов .gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore) для всех популярных языков программирования - просто выберите какой вам нужен и скопируйте к себе.

Comment: Ну, формально это у него имени нет, а вот расширение как раз-таки есть :)

Comment: Не до конца понял `Но если вы не понимаете зачем это` - что это? и насчет `любимом текстовом редакторе` - у меня нет любимого... Или вы что то другое имели ввиду и не смогли внятно выразить мысль?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, формально или неформально - имя файла и есть `.gitignore`. В Linux точка не несёт такого сакрального смысла, как в Windows. А если она первая в *имени* файла - это всего лишь "аналог" атрибута HIDDEN.

Comment: @PavelMayorov нет, в linux это часть имени. И имя у него - .gitignore. Расширения нет. Если через python попробовать получить расширение, то выводится os.path.splitext('.gitignore')
('.gitignore', '') - то есть расширения нет. В windows - возможно.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko если нет любимого, то пользуйтесь блокнотом

Comment: @PinkTux где в вопросе указано про Linux?

Comment: @FeroxTL а в Java большая часть способов [отсюда](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571223/how-do-i-get-the-file-extension-of-a-file-in-java) посчитает что `gitignore` - это расширение такое.

Comment: @PavelMayorov где в вопросе вообще указана ОС? Учитывая упоминание консольной утилиты автором вопроса ```echo``` можно только гадать что там у него

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а как часто в Windows файлы создают при помощи `echo`?

Comment: @PinkTux вот именно `.gitignore` я так частенько дописываю. Да, на винде.

Comment: @PinkTux кстати, не забывайте - с гитом в комплекте идет git bash - а это маленький юникс :)

Answer (score 2):

```
vim .gitignore
git add .gitignore
```

Содержимое файла составлять в зависимости от ваших нужд.

Т.е. если есть что то, что не имеет смысл ложить в проект (логи, кэши, временные файлы), то их и нужно добавлять в .gitignore.

Я бы советовал не брать какое то дефолтное содержимое файла, а добавлять в него по мере необходимости.

Я добавляю все скрытые файлы в игнор (`.*`), а на нужные скрытые делаю исключения (`!.travis.yml`). Пример файла .gitignore:

```
.*
!.keepdir
!.travis.yml
var/log/*
var/tmp/*
vendor/
```

Answer (score 1):

> посоветуйте что должно быть внутри файла?

Вот здесь ещё генератор `.gitignore` на всякие случаи: [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/)

По поводу использования - у меня, например, есть глобальный файл исключений, ссылка на который стоит в `~./gitconfig`:

```
[core]
    excludesfile = ~/.gitexcludes
```

В него занесены самые общие случаи для всех используемых языков/IDE, при этом необходимость в локальном `.gitignore` для проектов возникает редко.