# Игнорирование папок в GIT

Tags: git, gitignore

Столкнулся с проблемой, пользуюсь сброщиком проектов Grunt, при отправке на удаленный репозиторий хочу игнорировать папку

`node_modules` , но постоянно выбивает ошибку.
Пробую :

```
node_modules/ .gitignore
node_modules/* .gitignore
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста как правильно использовать в данном случае `.gitignore`, т.к. в этой папке очень много других папок и их все нужно игнорировать.

Comment: В корне проекта с гитом создаете файл `.gitignore` в котором прописываете `node_modules/`  .... всё

Comment: Скажите, а откуда вообще пришла в голову идея дописать `.gitignore` в конец строки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

создайте в корне проекта текстовый файл с именем `.gitignore` и впишите в него имена каталогов (в вашем конкретном случае — только один — `node_modules`), которые требуется игнорировать, по одному на строку.

проконтролируйте, чтобы ваш редактор в этом файле использовал в качестве [перевода строки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) символ `\n` (*lf*, *linefeed*), но не `\r` (*cr*, *carriage return*), и не их комбинацию `\r\n` (*crlf*).

---

полезная информация:

- [Как создать файл .gitignore в Windows?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/438367/178576)
- [Что должно и не должно быть в .gitignore для любого языка и IDE?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474556/178576)