# Сравнения null и undefined

Tags: javascript, преобразование-типов

Я читал о типах undefined и null и пришел к таким выводам:
undefined то же что и null, отличие лишь в том, что

```
var answer;
console.log(answer); // undefined
var answer = null;
console.log(answer); // null
```

undefined говорит что переменная была создана, но в нее ничего не записали.

null говорит что переменная была создана, но ее значение пока неизвестно.

Вопрос в следующем:

```
console.log(null==undefined) //true
console.log(null===undefined) //false
```

получается что оператор == сравнивает по значению, а === сравнивает по типу?

Comment: Это одна из известных ошибок дизайна языка к сожалению. Во первых то что null == undefined - жестко зашито в спеке. Семантика null когда-то в незапамятные времена задумывалась когда-то как несуществующий объект. Поэтому typeof(null) === 'object', а undefined - несуществующий примитив, typeof(undefined) === 'undefined'. У них есть и еще отличия, например +null (унарный плюс приводит к числу) - это ноль. +undefined - NaN. В общем это довольно разные штуки к сожалению, и их обе порой приходится иметь в виду

Comment: Ответ на вторую часть вопроса вы можете посмотреть например тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431662/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B8

Answer (score 3):

[Oracle Client-Side JavaScript Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/816-6408-10/ops.htm#1060974)

> **Equal (==)** Returns true if the operands are equal. If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript attempts to **convert** the operands to an appropriate type for the comparison.
>
> **Strict equal (===)** Returns true if the operands are equal and of **the same type**.

Comment: ok, but which will common type of operands if compare (undefined==null) ?

Comment: То, что цитата из документации на буржуйском, не означает, что SO.ru превратился в SO.en...

Comment: @AndreyFedorovich здесь все на русском, просто отвечающему было лень переводить спеку. Как я упомянул в своем комментарии undefined и null - это нефига не одно и то же, ваш эмпирический вывод просто неверен.

Comment: И я не вижу никакой необходимости выяснять, к какому типу надо приводить "ни хрена" и "хрен знает".

Comment: Ладно, на самом деле  @УткаУчитсяУкрываться ответил довольно понятно на мой вопрос, я с вами согласен, нет смысла выяснять какой будет общий тип))

Comment: @Akina, вот необходимость была бы, но в спеке в описании того как сравнивать теплое с мягким специально отдельно описан этот момент. Тут вопрос не столько в том как сравнивать "ни хрена" и "хрен знает" как "почему у нас две разные сущности почти на ровном месте" для "ни хрена" и "хрен знает"

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУкрываться *необходимость была бы* В таком случае пришлось бы приводить к типу undefined - он явно более общий :) только я даже представить не могу, как что-то привести к такому типу, не потеряв по дороге значения...

Comment: @Akina, в данный момент что попало пытаются в первую очередь привести к числу, поэтому интуитивное понимание обычного сравнения  у большинства разработчиков не знающих эти особенности такое: наверное null привели к нулю и undefined привели к нулю, поэтому они и равны. Что приводит к туче ошибок конечно когда выясняется что у null и undefined свои отличающиеся отношения с нулем. Необходимость "приводить к типу undefined" больше нигде не встречается, возможно чтобы не городить одну веточку алгоритма для конкретного случая этот пункт конкретно и был сделан...